# (Done) This question from a new contributor about getting fired should be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question [Impostor syndrome or will I get fired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/127098/impostor-syndrome-or-will-i-get-fired) should be reopened.

It already has some good answers.

And one of the folks voting to close it already provided an answer - not very nice.

Comment: VTRO  I agree, although, sometimes people will VTC just to get that 5th vote out of the way so they can then VTRO.

Comment: Voted to re-open!

Comment: I think the user that VTC after posting an answer may be responding to the fact that they are getting DVs for their answer - not nice at all.

Comment: VTRO, one vote left...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This question Impostor syndrome or will I get fired? should be reopened.

I agree. The post already received it's 5th and final vote, and now is open again.